# Manually populating the database with ASP.NET Identity schema (objects)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I already know you can use the REGISTRATION VIEW to automatically populate the target database by setting-up the views and (running) the registration form for a new account (when the DB doesn't exist yet).

However...I wish to populate the target database manually.

Is there a way I can:

- Populate the target database (for SQL Server & SQL Azure)
- Force all ID's to be UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS (e.g. Guids)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom storage provider for identity. I highly recommend checking out these articles:

[Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

[Change Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

[Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)